# All combinations of a mapped list of lists in python

Tags: python

Hi how can i get a mapped list to print all possible combinations

say the dict mapping is = {1:[a,b],2:[c,d]......

so with the list [1,2] and the sample mapping above I would like to print out all possible combinations of the pairs a,d against c,d into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

mapping = {1:['a','b'], 2:['c','d']}
data = [1, 2]
for combo in product(*(mapping[d] for d in data)):
    print combo
```

results in

```
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('b', 'c')
('b', 'd')
```

**Edit** it sounds like what you *actually* want is

```
strings = [''.join(combo) for combo in product(*(mapping[d] for d in data))]
```

which gives `strings == ['ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd']`.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the combinatoric functions in the [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).

If you're looking for all the pairings of `ab` against `cd`, the *product* function should help:

```
>>> d = {1: ['a','b'], 2: ['c', 'd']}
>>> for t in product(*d.values()):
        print t

('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('b', 'c')
('b', 'd')
```

If you're looking all combinations of `abcd` taken *r* at a time for the various sizes of *r*, then tthe *combinations* function should get the job done:

```
>>> for r in range(5):
        for t in combinations('abcd', r):
            print t

()
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('d',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('b', 'c')
('b', 'd')
('c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'd')
('b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: Next time, please include in your question the result that you actually wanted.  It is no fun guessing at your real need and then having you select another answer.